# Add report parameter that allows 'NOT IN'

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am building a report that has a dataset query something like:

(There are 4 work codes, 1, 2, 3, 4)

```
SELECT First, Last, WorkCode
FROM MyTable
WHERE Department = @Department
```

We want to add in a parameter that allows to the user to run the report with NO WorkCode 2, so the query would be:

```
SELECT First, Last, WorkCode
FROM MyTable
WHERE Department = @Department
AND WorkCode <> 2
```

but I am not sure how to do this without making two separate reports.

Comment: did you mean to say "but I am not sure how to do this WITHOUT making two separate reports"?

Comment: Opps, nice catch, thanks.,  I have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another Parameter to the report called WorkCode and add the variable name to the query.  In the report parameter properties window, under available values, select either "Specify Values" or "Get values from a query".

Here is what you make the last line of your query look like:

```
AND WorkCode <> @WorkCode
```

If you want the user to be able to select multiple values, select the "Allow multiple values" on the general tab of the Report Parameter Properties window and make the last line of the query look like this:

```
AND WorkCode NOT IN (@WorkCode)
```

And if the WorkCode param is optional, select the "Allow null value" checkbox in the properties window and do the following in your query:

```
 AND ((WorkCode NOT IN @WorkCode) OR (ISNULL(@WorkCode, '') = ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one Dataset for all the report items, based on your first query, and you can also add [filters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633648.aspx) to one or more report items to narrow the dataset further.

So if you wanted to stop `WorkCode` *2* showing up in a Tablix, you could apply a filter to that checks that `=Fields!WorkCode.Value` <> `2`.

Or you can make this parameter based, i.e. the filter will be `=Fields!WorkCode.Value` <> `=Parameters!WorkCode.Value`.